# When we install unmanage package in our org,do we need to rerun all the test classes?

Tags: package, unmanaged-package

When I install any unmanaged package in my org,do I need to rerun all the test classes? or Is it already covered in test class?

Lets say I create my own manage package in my org and cover all the test coverage to more than 75%.When I install it to another org there could be possibility that some validation rules enforce on object.So just wanted to confirm will it show more than 75%(same as my org) in other org?

Comment: Please note that while testing before packaging your product you should be testing for Positive/ Negative and Bulk cases. Achieving the 75% should not be your main objective but covering any possible scenarios your logic will encounter. As a result of this you should gain +75% code coverage anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test classes need to pass in the dev org when packaging. Not needed when installing

However, you should design your tests as best you can to pass in customer org. Also if performing call outs, provide a framework that your subscriber can use in their tests to mock responses when your package makes a call out during their tests.

So while they do not have to pass in subscriber org, there is a lot to consider and account for